# Using shadcn made on v0.dev is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13, shadcnui, vercel-ai

I have created a main page for my project using Next.js, the latest version + typescript app.

I have been using v0.dev for basic designs in HTML, but recently I have been using Typescript for my projects, so I made a basic design on it. Still, if I run the same code with install dependencies and shadcnui, I'm not getting the desired output on Chrome Browser...

I try to get the same output as displaying v0.dev but it's not working. Following are the images:

[Following are the files as follow:] [tsconfig file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfyPa.png)

[Components.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5N4d.png) [Errors in global.css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49EOC.png) [Despendencies installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Q2D.png) [This is the output I'm getting in Chrome Browser:] [Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO0DJ.png) [Expected Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNyLA.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).